# Find all solutions to the equation. $7 \sin^2x - 14 \sin x + 2 = -5$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I got this question wrong on a test and I want to see what I did wrong so I don't get this type of question wrong again.

Answer (score 5):

Hint, substitute:

$t = \sin(x)$

Answer (score 4):

First, add $5$ to both sides:
$$7 \sin^2 x - 14 \sin x + 7 = 0$$

Then, let $u = \sin x$, and substitute $u$ into the above equation:
$$7u^2 - 14u + 7 = 0$$

Then, divide both sides by $7$:

$$u^2 - 2u + 1 = 0$$

This may be factored as:

$$(u - 1)^2 = 0$$

so that we have $u - 1 = 0$, or $u = 1$.

Then since $u = \sin x$, we have $\sin x = 1$, giving $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k$, for any integer $k$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to merge the $2$ and the $-5$, and factor out a $7$
$$\begin{align}
7\sin^2 x-14\sin x + 2&=&-5\\
7\sin^2 x-14\sin x + 2+5&=&-5+5\\
7\sin^2 x-14\sin x + 7&=&0\\
7(\sin^2 x-2\sin x + 1)&=&0\\
\frac{1}{7}\cdot7(\sin^2 x-2\sin x + 1)&=&\frac{1}{7}\cdot0\\
\sin^2 x-2\sin x + 1&=&0\\
\end{align}$$
Now, try to realize that $\sin x$
 does not evaluate to the color blue, nor to a type of amoeba. It evaluates to a *number*. So, instead of reading the last line as
$$\text{the square of the sine of }x\text{ less twice the sine of }x\text{ plus one equals zero}$$
try reading it from a higher level
$$\text{the square of a number less twice that number plus one equals zero}$$
just as you would read
$$x^2-2x+1=0$$
as
$$\text{the square of a number less twice that number plus one equals zero}$$
or read
$$t^2-2t+1=0$$
as
$$\text{the square of a number less twice that number plus one equals zero}$$
or even read
$$\theta^2-2\theta+1=0$$
as
$$\text{the square of a number less twice that number plus one equals zero}$$
and lets not forget to read
$$u^2-2u+1=0$$
as
$$\text{the square of a number less twice that number plus one equals zero}$$
By now one should realize by interpreting $\sin x$ not as the value of a function evaluated at a number, but instead **interpret $\sin x$ as the number**, that factoring the expression becomes easy.
$$\begin{align}
\sin^2 x-2\sin x + 1&=&0\\
(\sin x-1)^2&=&0\\
\end{align}$$

Implying that $\sin x = 1$, thus $x = \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$

Comment: The period of $\sin x$ is $2\pi$, so $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + \color{red}{2}k\pi$.

Comment: ty NF, I had a brain f---. $\sin x = 0$ occurs twice per period, but $\sin x=1$ only occurs once.